# Is it possible to override HostAuthenticationFilter filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token, authorize-attribute

Is it possible to override `HostAuthenticationFilter` filter for customize the response message ?

this is configure as below:
Its a bearer token authorization.

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override this way:

```
public class HostAuthenticationFilterCustom : HostAuthenticationFilter
    {
        public HostAuthenticationFilterCustom(string authenticationType) : base(authenticationType)
        {
        }
        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.AuthenticateAsync(context,cancellationToken);
        }
        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.ChallengeAsync(context,cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to modify response object here ?

Comment: @user3711357 I don't know what you want, I showed that it is possible to override the Filter, how to use it is on you, not sure what you mean by response object, what is your goal, maybe your question is wrong defined.

Comment: If 401 response is found in `HostAuthenticationFilterCustom ` then how to modify the response and how to check wheather response is 401 or any other code.

Comment: Its not calling, registered filter globally.

Comment: Its not calling any of the method of `HostAuthenticationFilterCustom`, registered filter globally. Looks, its not overriden.

Comment: I've overridden the filter exactly like this, following your example. The constructor is called when the application starts up, but breakpoints in the `AuthenticateAsync` and `ChallengeAsync` methods are never hit. I'm having the same problem with methds in an overridden `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` I've created - the overridden methods just never get called.

Comment: Look at example from @abaustin above. Worked for me.